# How do a join in SQLITE c#

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.ios, sqlite-net

How do I get data with a join of two tables? This is my code but only I get data of `Classes` but also I want the attributes of `Active`

```
var q = db.Query<Classes>(
            "select * from Active a"
          + " inner join Classes c"
          + " on c.idAc = a._id").ToList();

return q.Select(x => new Classes { Id= x.Id, name = x.name})
        .ToList();
```

I want to get the attributes of Active table as well, this `Id= x.Id, name = x.name` belongs to `Classes` table

Comment: I think you are at least missing a closing quote (`"`) - this code most likely doesn't compile

Comment: You probably have good result from JOIN statement, you but you are returning data only from Classes.

Comment: @PiotrP i want all datas of the two tables

Comment: @Rafalon ok i've edited my question thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, you want to get Id, name attributes  from table Classes, and get detail attributes  from table Active, so you should create new class tabledetail to contains these attributes.

```
public class tabledetail
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string detail { get; set; }
}

var q = db.Query<tabledetail>(
        "select c.Id,c.name,a.detail from Active a"
    + " inner join Classes c"
    + " on c.idAc = a._id").ToList();
        return q.Select(x => new tabledetail
        { Id = x.Id, name = x.name ,detail=x.detail }).ToList();
```

Here is the same thread that you can take a look:

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/36809/joining-tables-in-sqlite-net-and-returning-object-with-fields-from-both-tables

Answer (score 0):

I would try with something like:

```
class Response{
var idClasses;
var nameClasses;
var attributeActive1;
var attributeActive2;
(...)
}
var q = db.Query<Classes>(
            "select * from Active a"
        + " inner join Classes c"
        + " on c.idAccount = a._id").ToList();
           return q.Select(x => new Response
            { idClasses= x.Id, nameClasses = x.name, attributeActive1 = att1, 
               attributeActive2 = att2, (...)}).ToList();
```

Comment: x. only have atributes of Classes table

Comment: I understand, change also db.Query<Classes> to db.Query<Response>

Comment: @mikkylekyle please define "*do not work*": is there an error message?